# Populate values to dropdown list from a JSON file using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a html dropdown list. On page load, I have to populate the values from a JSON.JS file using Jquery.

The JSON file contains:

```
var accounts = ["WHDH","TF"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the json.js has been added:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDropdown').empty(); // empty the dropdown (if necessarry)
    $(accounts).each(function(iIndex, sElement) {
        $('#myDropdown').append('<option>' + sElement + '</option>');
    });
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/cU8rW/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '';
jQuery.each(accounts, function(i , item) {
   html += '<option value="'+item+'">'+item+'</option>';
}
jQuery('#dropdown').append(html);
```

Technically, this variant is faster since we only call the resource-intensive `.append()` once. But you only really 'feel' the difference once you try to add 100+ items.