# Show Selected Value From Database Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, select

How can I show the years, 2009, 2010, etc.  which are returned from a database, these values are in Table2

A separate table Table1 has the selected Value.

The main problem is, Table1 has YearSelected 2012, but I also need the value,, 2009, 2010, 2011 from Table 2.  It has to be done all in JQuery?  Can someone point me to a working example?

I'm a newbie and have ran into a brick wall.  thx

```
<select id="year_selected"  name="YearSelected">
    <option>-Select Year-</option>
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This question has been answered here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224095/populate-values-to-dropdown-list-from-a-json-file-using-jquery

Comment: That only shows how to append to the dropdown.  Would I have to make 2 calls to the database?  One for the initial value and then a follow up to add the options?  If so, where is a good sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
 <select id="year_selected"  name="YearSelected">
        <option>-Select Year-</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       // $('#year_selected').empty();  empty the dropdown (if necessarry)
        $(accounts).each(function(iIndex, sElement) {
            $('#year_selected').append('<option>' + sElement + '</option>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm new at this, isn't that just to add the options?  I need a value from table1, and options from table2, would I need to make more than one trip to the database?